# Is there any way to retrieve data asyncronously in a LibreOffice python addin?

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, uno

I implemented a simple addin in python to retrieve stocks prices and other data via an API.
It works ok, however I have many tickers and the whole thing blocks for a few minutes because each cell is evaluated one by one and the latency to the API just adds up.

Is there any way to launch a thread and return a temporary "loading..." value and repopulate the cell with data when it becomes available? I've tried doing it but the documentation is very scarce and I couldn't find out how to populate the data from the threads after the requests finishes.

The code is simple and looks like this:

```
import json
import urllib.request

import uno
import unohelper
from com.stizard.api import XStizardApi

class StizardImpl(unohelper.Base, XStizardApi):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx
    def stizardPrice(self, symbol):
        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.example.com/prices/prices.php?symbol=" + symbol) as response:
            rawResponse = response.read()
            data = json.loads(rawResponse)
            return data['price']
    def stizard(self, symbol, q = "price"):
        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.example.com/prices/prices.php?symbol=" + symbol +"&q=" + q) as response:
            rawResponse = response.read()
            data = json.loads(rawResponse)
            return data['price']

def createInstance(ctx):
    return StizardImpl(ctx)
g_ImplementationHelper = unohelper.ImplementationHelper()
g_ImplementationHelper.addImplementation(
    createInstance,
    "com.stizard.api.python.StizardImpl",
    ("com.sun.star.sheet.AddIn",)
)
```

Later edit:
idl file XStizardApi.idl

```
#include <com/sun/star/uno/XInterface.idl>

module com { module stizard { module api {

    interface XStizardApi {
        double stizardPrice( [in] string symbol );
        string stizard( [in] string symbol, [in] string q);
    };

}; }; };
```

description.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<description xmlns="http://openoffice.org/extensions/description/2006"
xmlns:d="http://openoffice.org/extensions/description/2006"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<dependencies>
    <OpenOffice.org-minimal-version value="2.4" d:name="OpenOffice.org 2.4"/>
</dependencies>

<identifier value="com.stizard.api" />
<version value="1.0.0" />
<display-name><name lang="en">Stizard API</name></display-name>
<publisher><name xlink:href="http://www.github.com/" lang="en">Stizard.com</name></publisher>

</description>
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your example but am having trouble with the new `unoidl-write.exe`. If you used the new tool (not the old `idlc.exe`), then would you mind editing the question to show your IDL file along with the terminal command to compile it to RDB.

Comment: It seems like an add-in would not be the right way to change cells more than once, as they simply return a value. Instead, update the cells by assigning python code to be run when an event occurs such as document loading. Be sure to run in a separate thread so that the GUI doesn't get locked while downloading the data, for example https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/python-macro-calc-stuck-with-getcellbyposition-and-threads/53705/3.

Comment: @JimK I updated the post with the idl file and description.xml, I use linux and my example is based om http://www.github.com/prikhi/libreoffice-binance-api/

Comment: Okay, thanks for adding those details. That project uses [idlc.exe which is deprecated in 7.4](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/tools.html#idlc). Binary RDB files work in current versions, but in future versions, they may no longer work. Anyway, that is not important to your question, but please consider my second comment above.